# State of Handles.RotationHandle()

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can I somehow find out is it the first frame the user click on rotater, last frame or middle?

```
Handles.RotationHandle(...)
```

or

```
Handles.PositionHandle(...)
```

I need to know when the user start rotating/moving and when stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Then you just need to add a variable to save the state. Something like this:

```
bool rotating;
void Update () {
    if (rotating != Handles.RotationHandle(..)) {
        rotating = !rotating;
        if (rotating) {
            //start rotation
        } else {
            //just stopped
        }
    } else if (rotating) {
        //in rotating
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work. 'RotationHandle' returns 'Quaternion', not the 'boolean'

Comment: Oh, that would be hard.

Comment: Maybe you could make a Quaternion variable. When it changes, that means the user started rotating. This isn't very accurate but maybe my last idea.